# What is the difference between Task and Async? And is this the HomoGeneous way?

Tags: c++

I am studying MultiThreading.

Among the things I found
'HeteroGeneous', 'HomoGeneous', 'Task', 'Async'
I learned a total of 4 words.
I understand that 'HeteroGeneous' is a method of calculating each 'Thread' by distributing its role.
In the case of 'HomoGeneous', I understand that it is a method of repeatedly calculating by giving a task to the resting 'Thread'.

1. Is the contents of 'Task' and 'Async' connected and used in combination?
2. 'Task' and 'Async' Is it part of the 'HomoGeneous' method?

Comment: You need to refer to the sources you read, because as there is no other tags mentioned in the question it is not clear what you mean. Are you referring in the context of high performance computing (HPC) or exascale computing?

Comment: In c++ async (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is an "abstracted" way of starting (and synchronizing with) functions asynchronously without having to know HOW the asynchronisity is implemented (might even "work" on a single threaded cpu by cooperative multitasking), but usually it uses threads. I prefer this over using std::thread. A task is something that can be run asynchronously and contains a function, its result (and something called a promise), and may have methods on it like cancel/abort. (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

Comment: This sounds like a candidate for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.